# SVG mouse event unsyncronized if window scrolled

Tags: svg, scroll

I don't know how to properly explain this.

I have a svg element which is a big rectangle. If i scroll down, then click on my element, the click isn't registered where my mouse is, but where my mouse would be if i didn't scroll down.

So, if i scroll down by 100px and click on my rectangle, the click will be registered 100px above where i actually clicked.

It's behaving as if i hadn't scrolled down.

**Edit**: *I'm using event.clientX and event.clientY to get the mouse position*.

I'm new to svg and i don't know the right keywords to describe my problem.
I'm using svg.js, though i don't think it's relevant to the problem.

I assume this is a well known thing. Can someone point me in the right direction? What kind of keyword am i looking for here?

The problem seems simple enough, i just need to know what to search for.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit you question and show us the relevant code. "Mouse event" and "coordinates" are good terms to describe your problem. Read up on [viewports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts). and look at the [MouseEvent.clientX example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#Example) to understand the difference between `client` and `screen` values.

Comment: I'll do that. Here, i'm using event.clientX and event.clientY. I visited you link on mouse events, and i see that there are also pageX and pageY properties, as well as screenX/screenY. I'll do some tests and edit my question.

Comment: @ccprog Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I could find my answer in the links you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the utilization of (event.clientX, event.clientY) to get the mouse position.

In the presence of a vertical and/or horizontal scroll, using these properties caused a mismatch between where the mouse appeared within the page and the mouse position provided by (event.clientX, event.clientY).

I was using the mousedown event, with the mousemove event to create a selection rectangle, similar to what you can find in video games. When horizontal or vertical scrolling had been applied, my selection rectangle didn't appear where my mouse was.

This was **solved by using event.pageX and event.pageY** (instead of clientX and clientY).

Thank you to @ccprog for pointing me in the right direction.